# google reviews with places API - no data for business with hidden address?

Tags: google-maps

I was trying to embed google plus reviews on my website using the google places api.  The following link is the process I used to set this up.

http://gurutechnolabs.tumblr.com/post/112214772991/how-to-embed-google-reviews-using-google-places

When I enter https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=yourAPIKey&query=YourPlace into the browser I don't get any data when I enter my business name.  I do get data when I enter a different business name.  I suspect the issue is my business address isn't public as I serve customers only at their location.  Is this the issue and any way to use this feature with a hidden address? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your business is defined as Service Area Buiseness, it will not be accessible via Places API search or Places API autocomplete.

If this is feasible, try to change the type of the business in Google My Business. Not sure if it will be possible to extract reviews by a place ID, however, it's not easy to figure out what is the place ID of your business.

Can I have the link to your business in Google Plus for further investigation?